# jQuery Collapse not working in my modal

Tags: jquery

I've a code where the collapse is working as it should be, but when I use it in my own script it doesn't work and I don't know where to look. Here is the working code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-test.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
<h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 1</h3>  
  <div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;padding: 10px;">
   <div style="padding-left: 12px;float: left;"> <h4>Keywords:</h4>
   Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br />
   Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br />
   Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br />
  </div>

    <div id="previewBox1">
        <div class="previewBox1">
    <div style="margin-top: 0px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;">Ad1</div>
    <div id="headlineText" style="color: #00c;font-size: 14px;text-decoration: underline;padding-left: 12px;">
    <span id="headlineText11" >hjgj ghjgjh</span>
    <span id="headlineText2101">ghjgjh hjjgjh</span><br />
    <img src="ads.jpg" style="float: left;" /><span style="color: #0e8f0e; " id="finalUrlText501">www.example.com</span><span id="path1Text301" style="color: #0e8f0e;">/hjgjghjghj/</span><span id="path2Text401" style="color: #0e8f0e;"tyrtytyytry</span>
    </div>
    <span id="descriptionText201" style="padding-left: 12px;">rytrytnyytut</span>
</div>
<div class="previewBox1">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;">Ad 2</div>
    <div id="headlineText" style="color: #00c;font-size: 14px;text-decoration: underline;padding-left: 12px;">
    <span id="headlineText11" >hjgj ghjgjh</span>
    <span id="headlineText2101">ghjgjh hjjgjh</span><br />
    <img src="ads.jpg" style="float: left;" /><span style="color: #0e8f0e; " id="finalUrlText501">www.example.com</span><span id="path1Text301" style="color: #0e8f0e;">/hjgjghjghj/</span><span id="path2Text401" style="color: #0e8f0e;"tyrtytyytry</span>
    </div>
    <span id="descriptionText201" style="padding-left: 12px;">rytrytnyytut</span>
</div>

    </div>


<div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>

  </div>



  <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 2</h3>  
  <div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">
  Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
  </div>
  <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 3</h3>  
  <div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">
 Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
  </div>
 <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 4</h3>  
  <div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">

   Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
  </div>
</div>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my script I'm adding the collapse code my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Your Campaign Preview</h4>
        </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="accordion"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

using this code :

```
document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = '<h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 1</h3><div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;padding: 10px;"><div style="padding-left: 12px;float: left;"> <h4>Keywords:</h4>Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br />Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br />Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br /></div><div id="previewBox1"><div class="previewBox1"><div style="margin-top: 0px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;">Ad1</div><div id="headlineText" style="color: #00c;font-size: 14px;text-decoration: underline;padding-left: 12px;"><span id="headlineText11" >hjgj ghjgjh</span><span id="headlineText2101">ghjgjh hjjgjh</span><br /><img src="ads.jpg" style="float: left;" /><span style="color: #0e8f0e; " id="finalUrlText501">www.example.com</span><span id="path1Text301" style="color: #0e8f0e;">/hjgjghjghj/</span><span id="path2Text401" style="color: #0e8f0e;"tyrtytyytry</span></div><span id="descriptionText201" style="padding-left: 12px;">rytrytnyytut</span></div><div class="previewBox1"><div style="margin-top: 10px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;">Ad 2</div>    <div id="headlineText" style="color: #00c;font-size: 14px;text-decoration: underline;padding-left: 12px;"><span id="headlineText11" >hjgj ghjgjh</span><span id="headlineText2101">ghjgjh hjjgjh</span><br /><img src="ads.jpg" style="float: left;" /><span style="color: #0e8f0e; " id="finalUrlText501">www.example.com</span><span id="path1Text301" style="color: #0e8f0e;">/hjgjghjghj/</span><span id="path2Text401" style="color: #0e8f0e;"tyrtytyytry</span></div><span id="descriptionText201" style="padding-left: 12px;">rytrytnyytut</span></div></div><div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div></div>  <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 2</h3><div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate. </div><h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 2</h3><div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate. </div>';
```

The content is well inserted, but the divs are expanded instead of having the first one expanded and the others collapsed.
I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what it is. I've added the jQuery-ui CDN to the header and the function() too to my code.

Help me please.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The above codes are not in good practice for a developer unless you are a beginner. You didn't call bootstrap, but you tried to use it. Betterlook at bootstrap tutorials and its easy for you [Bootstrap collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/). Don't add dirty codes which make difficulties to others to find what actually happens.

For Eg, after calling bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Button collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
    //your statements
</div>
```

Actually easy

Comment: I'm sorry for the messy code. Yes, I'm a hardcore beginner. I normally play with the code and CSS till it works and then I clean it. Sorry again. I don't use bootstrap on the test code (the first code in my post) and it's working great. Bootstrap is used for my nodal and I call it on my actual code.

Comment: I just updated my answer and bootstrap is so easy, you can easily understand, just go through it

Comment: I've worked for a half day to make my code works and display the way I want it. I agree that Bootstrap may be easier, but for the sake of learning, I want to know what is the problem with my actual code. Thank you again.

Comment: May be you you are looking for `append()` jquey function, Please clear your codes

Answer (score 0):

Add following line after your code `document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = ...`

```
$("#accordion").accordion('destroy').accordion();
```

You can check working sample below. On `Update HTML` button click it will update your html and then reset `accordion`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion();
});

function setNewHtml() {
  document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = '<h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 1</h3><div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;padding: 10px;"><div style="padding-left: 12px;float: left;"> <h4>Keywords:</h4>Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br />Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br />Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br /></div><div id="previewBox1"><div class="previewBox1"><div style="margin-top: 0px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;">Ad1</div><div id="headlineText" style="color: #00c;font-size: 14px;text-decoration: underline;padding-left: 12px;"><span id="headlineText11" >hjgj ghjgjh</span><span id="headlineText2101">ghjgjh hjjgjh</span><br /><img src="ads.jpg" style="float: left;" /><span style="color: #0e8f0e; " id="finalUrlText501">www.example.com</span><span id="path1Text301" style="color: #0e8f0e;">/hjgjghjghj/</span><span id="path2Text401" style="color: #0e8f0e;"tyrtytyytry</span></div><span id="descriptionText201" style="padding-left: 12px;">rytrytnyytut</span></div><div class="previewBox1"><div style="margin-top: 10px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;">Ad 2</div>    <div id="headlineText" style="color: #00c;font-size: 14px;text-decoration: underline;padding-left: 12px;"><span id="headlineText11" >hjgj ghjgjh</span><span id="headlineText2101">ghjgjh hjjgjh</span><br /><img src="ads.jpg" style="float: left;" /><span style="color: #0e8f0e; " id="finalUrlText501">www.example.com</span><span id="path1Text301" style="color: #0e8f0e;">/hjgjghjghj/</span><span id="path2Text401" style="color: #0e8f0e;"tyrtytyytry</span></div><span id="descriptionText201" style="padding-left: 12px;">rytrytnyytut</span></div></div><div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div></div>  <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 2</h3><div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate. </div><h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 2</h3><div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate. </div>';



  $("#accordion").accordion('destroy').accordion();
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-test.css">

<button onclick="setNewHtml()"> Update HTML </button>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 1</h3>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;padding: 10px;">
    <div style="padding-left: 12px;float: left;">
      <h4>Keywords:</h4>
      Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br /> Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br /> Mauris mauris ante, blandit¸<br />
    </div>

    <div id="previewBox1">
      <div class="previewBox1">
        <div style="margin-top: 0px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;">Ad1</div>
        <div id="headlineText" style="color: #00c;font-size: 14px;text-decoration: underline;padding-left: 12px;">
          <span id="headlineText11">hjgj ghjgjh</span>
          <span id="headlineText2101">ghjgjh hjjgjh</span><br />
          <img src="ads.jpg" style="float: left;" /><span style="color: #0e8f0e; " id="finalUrlText501">www.example.com</span><span id="path1Text301" style="color: #0e8f0e;">/hjgjghjghj/</span><span id="path2Text401" style="color: #0e8f0e;" tyrtytyytry</span>
        </div>
        <span id="descriptionText201" style="padding-left: 12px;">rytrytnyytut</span>
      </div>
      <div class="previewBox1">
        <div style="margin-top: 10px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;">Ad 2</div>
        <div id="headlineText" style="color: #00c;font-size: 14px;text-decoration: underline;padding-left: 12px;">
          <span id="headlineText11">hjgj ghjgjh</span>
          <span id="headlineText2101">ghjgjh hjjgjh</span><br />
          <img src="ads.jpg" style="float: left;" /><span style="color: #0e8f0e; " id="finalUrlText501">www.example.com</span><span id="path1Text301" style="color: #0e8f0e;">/hjgjghjghj/</span><span id="path2Text401" style="color: #0e8f0e;" tyrtytyytry</span>
        </div>
        <span id="descriptionText201" style="padding-left: 12px;">rytrytnyytut</span>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>

  </div>



  <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 2</h3>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
    a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
  </div>
  <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 3</h3>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
    a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
  </div>
  <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;font-size: 18px;padding-left: 12px;background-color: whitesmoke;border-bottom: #dfdeda;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-top-right-radius: 3px;margin-bottom: auto;">Adgroup 4</h3>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 12px;border: 1px solid rgb(223, 222, 218);border-radius: 3px;">

    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
    a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but it messes my css :( https://image.ibb.co/jAk2XT/Capture1.jpg